# path url is reformatted when opening clicking on a tag

Tags: php, html, encoding, href

I have some image path whose `url` outputs this way (using php smarty escaping)

```
<a href="/documents/Capture+d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran+2014-07-08+%C3%A0+19.33.51.png"></a>
```

but when I click, on this doc the browser opens a âge wholes is

```
`www.mysite.com/documents/Capture+d’écran+2014-07-08+à+19.33.51.png`
```

It seems that it is formatted in incorrect format. How can I deal with that

Comment: what should the actual name of the file be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use url_encode() and url_decode() function for remove this type of error.

Comment: If you are talking about PHP's urlencode()/urldecode() then, it'll not work at here. Because, his URL is actually a image link rather than a PHP script file.